# Rsyslog stops sending messages to /var/log/messages if configured to forward them

Tags: rsyslog

Why does **Rsyslog** stop sending messages to `/var/log/messages` when I add `*.* @@10.0.1.92` to the end of the file?

If I comment that line, it starts sending messages to **/var/log/messages** again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, rsyslog uses queues for actions (outputs). If you don't specify a queue, the default queue is used. Each queue is also synchronous; if you don't provide a way to execute actions concurrently, one hanging action (e.g., message forwarding) can block causing the others actions to not be reached.

reference:

- https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/concepts/queues.html
- https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/rainerscript/queue_parameters.html#example-1
- https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/concepts/multi_ruleset.html